On Tiptap using BulletList and OrderedList with shift+enter
I had to change the behavior of Enter to make it run a function (this not a option, it has to be like this). Because of this, neither the bullet list nor the ordered list are working properly.
What is happening is that when I press Shift+Enter to break to a new line, it does not give me a new li as it does when just pressing Enter (in normal circumstances).
I've tried a lot of things to make the line break give me a new li, but nothing has helped.
const MenuBar = ({ editor }) => {
  return (

    <>
      <div className='menu-tiptap'>
       <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            editor.chain().focus().toggleBulletList().run()}}
          className={editor.isActive('bulletList') ? 'is-active' : ''}
        >  <RiListUnordered/>
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            editor.chain().focus().toggleOrderedList().run()}}
          className={editor.isActive('orderedList') ? 'is-active' : ''}
        > <RiListOrdered2/>
        </button>
      </div>   
    </>
  )
}



const getExtensions = (menu, postWithEnter,) => {
  let extensions = [
    StarterKit,
    BulletList,
    OrderedList,
    Heading.configure({
      levels: [1, 2, 3],
    }),
  ];

  if (menu) {
    extensions.push(Mention.configure({
      HTMLAttributes: {
        class: 'mention',
      },
      suggestion,
    }));
  }

  if (postWithEnter) {
    extensions.push(Extension.create({
      addKeyboardShortcuts() {
        return {
          Enter: () => {
            const button = document.getElementById('submit-button');
            if (button) {
              button.click();
    }
            return true
          },
          'Shift-Enter': () => {
            return false
          }, }  }, }));}
  return extensions;
}

const Tiptap = ({setContent, menu, postWithEnter, ) => {
  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: getExtensions(menu, postWithEnter, ),
    content: '<p> </p>',
    onUpdate: ({editor}) => {  
      const text = editor.getHTML();
      setContent(text);
    },
  });

  const clearContent = () => {
    if (editor && postWithEnter) {
      editor.commands.clearContent();
    }
  }
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const button = document.getElementById('submit-button');
    if (button && postWithEnter) {
      button.addEventListener('click', clearContent);
    }
    
    return () => {
      if (button && postWithEnter) {
        button.removeEventListener('click', clearContent);
      }
    }
  }, [editor, postWithEnter]); 


  if (!editor) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <div className='container-tiptap'>
        <EditorContent editor={editor} /> 

        {menu ?      
          <div className='wrap-menu-tiptap'>
            <MenuBar editor={editor}/>
          </div> :  <></>}
 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tiptap

